# Tidyverse's Nested Dataframes workflow in the Pandas

Tags: python, r, pandas, dataframe, tidyverse

What is the best workflow for using the nested data frames in the pandas?
`Tidyverse` allows for an excellent workflow with nested data frames and hence saves us a lot of for cycles.

However, for the Pandas the API is not quite there just yet.

Let's consider an example in `R`:

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- iris

model <- function(df) {
  model <- lm(Sepal.Length ~ Sepal.Width + Petal.Length, data = df)
  return(model)
}

nested <- 
  df %>% 
  group_by(Species) %>% 
  nest()

nested %>% 
  mutate(res = map(data, ~model(.)))
```

What would be the equivalent in `Pandas`?

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns

df = sns.load_dataset('iris')
```

Comment: your code would make sense to someone who is familiar with the concept. Kindly share sample dataframe(s) with expected output. and make it understandable to someone within python/pandas space

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`datar`](https://github.com/pwwang/datar):

```py
>>> from datar.datasets import iris as df
>>> from datar.all import f, group_by, nest, mutate
>>> from pipda import register_func
>>> 
>>> class Model:
...     def __init__(self, data):
...         ...
... 
>>> @register_func(None)
... def model(data):
...     # define your own model, or compute the model using other libraries
...     return [Model(dat) for dat in data]
... 
>>> nested = df >> group_by(f.Species) >> nest()
>>> nested
      Species       data
     <object>   <object>
0      setosa  <DF 50x4>
1  versicolor  <DF 50x4>
2   virginica  <DF 50x4>

[Groups: Species (n=3)]
>>> 
>>> nested >> mutate(res=model(f.data))
      Species       data                                        res
     <object>   <object>                                   <object>
0      setosa  <DF 50x4>  <__main__.Model object at 0x7f28ca974e90>
1  versicolor  <DF 50x4>  <__main__.Model object at 0x7f28ca9a5890>
2   virginica  <DF 50x4>  <__main__.Model object at 0x7f28ca9a5a10>

[Groups: Species (n=3)]
```

I am the author of the [`datar`](https://github.com/pwwang/datar) package. Feel free to submit issues if you have any questions.